# Android - How to choose context?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-canvas

I have an issue with a finger painting program. In this program I implement two fragments, and I have come to realize that my drawing fragment, which is to contain a canvas and support drawing onto it, is not displaying the canvas, and has other problems. My realization is tied to my noticing that while I wrote a new class to extend View (done because the fragment would not support extending view itself), I did not instantiate the class. I have made an instance of the class within the fragment, but this instance requires a Context as a parameter, and I'm not sure what context to use. I tried using 'getActivity()' as the context, but that did not work and made the program hang (in debug) or crash (in normal mode). What should I be using for the context of this class instantiation?

Fragment Code:

```
package com.example.chris.drawingtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.chris.drawingtest.R;

/**
 * Created by Chris on 11/28/2014.
 */
public class DrawingFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("onCreateView: ","This ran successfully");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawing, container, false);
    }

    private class DrawView extends View {

        private Path drawpath = new Path();
        private Paint drawpaint = new Paint();
        private Paint canvaspaint;
        private Canvas drawcanvas;
        private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

        private int paintColor = 0xFF000000;    //opaque black for pencil
        private int canvasColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;   //pure white for canvas

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            Log.d("DrawView: ", "method is called");

            drawpaint.setColor(paintColor);

            drawpaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
            drawpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            drawpaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            drawpaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

            canvaspaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            Point p = getScreenSize(context);
            int w = p.x;
            int h = p.y;

            OnSizeChanged(w,h,0,0);

        }

        protected Point getScreenSize(Context context) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            return size;
        }

        protected void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);

            Log.d("OnSizeChanged: ", "method is called");

            canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            drawcanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            Log.d("onDraw: ", "method is called");

            drawcanvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap,0,0,canvaspaint);
            canvas.drawPath(drawpath, drawpaint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();

            Log.d("onTouchEvent: ", "method is called");

            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    drawpath.moveTo(touchX,touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    drawpath.lineTo(touchX,touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    drawcanvas.drawPath(drawpath, drawpaint);
                    drawpath.reset();
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    //private DrawView drawView = new DrawView();    this is the problematic instantiation

}
```

**EDIT:** I wanted to add some new content to reflect answers given.

Following the ideas put forth by Bruce, I expanded upon XML file for DrawingFragment. Unfortunately, this led to further crashes, no doubt with some of my own naivety to blame. Can anyone share some insight on this issue?

logcat:

```
12-01 15:38:50.116    8045-8045/com.example.chris.drawingtest D/onCreateView:﹕ This ran successfully
12-01 15:38:50.126    8045-8045/com.example.chris.drawingtest D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-01 15:38:50.126    8045-8045/com.example.chris.drawingtest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c9aba8)
12-01 15:38:50.126    8045-8045/com.example.chris.drawingtest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chris.drawingtest, PID: 8045
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chris.drawingtest/com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingFragment$DrawView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingFragment$DrawView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingFragment.onCreateView(DrawingFragment.java:32)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingActivity.onCreate(DrawingActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingFragment.onCreateView(DrawingFragment.java:32)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingActivity.onCreate(DrawingActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingFragment"
    >

    <view
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        class="com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingFragment$DrawView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `getActivity()` is fine. I am sure the issue has nothing to do with the `Context` you pick.

Comment: I tried it again with the line commented out and adding "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.set_debug_app"></uses-permission>" to the manifest file, but still it hangs on waiting for the debugger. So I'm not sure what is actually causing this problem. 

The program does run correctly with the line commented out though, so I think that creating the DrawView object with getActivity() was causing the problem. You may be right, however, that it is another issue and not the actual use of getActivity() which is causing the problem.

Comment: I also tried another trick which said that resetting android studio and the device could fix the debug hang-up, but alas it was no use for mine.

Comment: Restart the adb daemon, if you don't know how to do that then just restart your computer.

Comment: Restarting the computer worked. Unfortunately I am still getting issues with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1) You've made your View subclass as an inner class of your Fragment, which means that there is an implied DrawingFragment parameter to each constructor. This means that your View does not have the standard constructors that Android requires to construct Views from XML. You should either make the inner class static, or put it in its own file.

2) You have OnSizeChanged (cap O), which does not override the lower-case version, and then you call the super's version. I see you are calling your version from your constructor, but if Android resizes your view for some reason, you won't hear about it.

3) You might want to keep track of the current size of your canvas, so you can avoid re-creating it each time onSizeChanged is called. They might have fixed this, but in the past I've seen multiple calls to this function, with the same size.

4) Are you sure you want to use the screen size for the canvas? This would include areas that you can't actually draw on. It would be better to have your fragment and your view as match_parent in width and height, and then just wait for Android to tell you your size in onSizeChanged. If you have your DrawView in the fragment's layout file R.layout.fragment_drawing (which is what you should do), then you can set the match_parent attributes in there.

5) Speaking of attribute, when Android inflates a View from XML, they use a different constructor than the Context-only version. I would recommend the common pattern below for your custom View:

```
public DrawView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    //TODO your constructor body here
}
```

EDIT

Answering the question about how to instantiate a custom view. It sounds like your DrawView takes up your entire fragment, so I'll write it that way. However, you could of course also have a parent view like RelativeLayout as the root of the file, and make DrawView the child. Another thing that affects the answer is whether DrawView is still an inner class of your fragment. The simpler case is if DrawView is in its own file. Then you can do this:

```
<com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

If you are keeping DrawView as a static inner class, then you use the '$' separator rather than '.'. However, '$' is a special character for XML, so you can't use it in your tag. You can, however, specify the class name as an XML attribute of a view tag. Like this:

```
<view
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    class="com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingFragment$DrawView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

EDIT:

Yes, this crash is exactly the problem I was talking about in #1 and #5 above. The exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]` is telling you that Android can't find a View constructor that takes a Context and AttributeSet (the 2nd of the 3 constructors I showed). Make sure your DrawView class is public, static, and that you include all the constructors.

```
public class DrawingFragment extends Fragment {
    public static class DrawView extends View {
    ... // 3 constructors shown above
```

EDIT:

Since you want the draw fragment on top of another fragment, and taking up most of the screen, I would use a RelativeLayout as the root view of your activity, then put your smaller bottom view next, with wrap_content height, and then your draw fragment above that. You can use the RelativeLayout params to anchor your fragments to the top and bottom of the activity. So layout/draw_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/tools_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        class="com.example.chris.drawingtest.ToolsFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/draw_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/tools_fragment"
        class="com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then presuming your DrawView fills your DrawingFragment, you can use the XML I already showed.

Comment: Thank you for the many points of advice. If you don't mind me asking, how would you put a DrawView into the fragment's layout file? Something like <DrawingFragment.DrawView> ...content here... </DrawingFragment.DrawView> ?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I added some more based on this to the original question.

Comment: Reply added to my answer.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I didn't realize that when I looked at other people's programs in examples or in other questions that the multiple constructors were necessary. The program no longer crashes, and the drawing is actually working somewhat, so I'm happy about that. Still some more problems to fix but I'll keep working and ask questions as I need. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: As an additional question, about part 4 of your answer, I tried to make the drawingfragment and the view have width and height of "match_parent", but maybe I did something wrong, because after doing so the program would just not display any fragments at all! I don't know what would cause that, could you shed any light on that situation? I can add more code as necessary.

Comment: If it was working better before, then I'd say just put it back like it was. The layout of the view depends on whether you have other views (e.g. drawing tools) inside the fragment. The layout you use for the fragment depends on how it fits into its parent activity.

Comment: Well, what I'd like for it to do is to have the drawing space fragment fill most of the screen, but for the bottom of the screen to have another fragment I designed as a toolbar for switching tools. Even in the functional version, the drawing fragment takes up the entire screen (probably because of my grabbing the entire screen size). I don't want to just make it a hard-coded size, as it needs to fit on multiple screens. I didn't quite understand what you meant when you mentioned how to deal with it in part 4 of your response. Could you please elaborate on how I might solve this problem?

Comment: I added some XML for your activity. I think if you have more issues, you should start a new question. This one is getting pretty long.

Comment: Agreed. I'll try your recommendation and ask a new question for it if I run into more trouble. Until then, if you were still willing to help, would you be willing to look at another question of mine?  ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238828/android-communicating-between-fragments-accessing-class-inside-fragment ) Either way, thank you so much for all your help. You're a real lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating your custom `View` outside of the aptly named `onCreateView`? Perhaps give this a try:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("onCreateView: ","This ran successfully");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawing, container, false);
    drawView = new DrawView(v.getContext());
    //and then add drawView wherever you want it within fragment_drawing
    //((ViewGroup)v).addView(drawView); *change this to where you want the view and with the appropriate casting and layout parameters*
    return v;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why that didn't occur to me, but it did fix the crashing problem. Thanks very much for your help.