# android - Communicating between fragments - accessing class inside fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am attempting to communicate between two fragments in an android program. I've been following this guide [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) and everything is going well so far. I have the one fragment sending data to its host activity, and the activity correctly acknowledges the data through Log statements. I have also successfully referenced the second fragment within the activity, and am all set to send this information to another fragment, but therein lies the problem; the method in the second fragment, which I need to call from the host activity, is inside of another class inside of the fragment, and what's more, that method relies on data which is defined inside of the fragment. I've tried to call the method directly, but I cannot seem to do it. Is there some way of getting past these limitations?

Host Activity:

```
package com.example.chris.drawingtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class DrawingActivity extends Activity
    implements ToolbarFragment.ToolSelectionListener {

    public void sendNewValue(int newValue) {
        Log.d("Data received from Toolbar Fragment: ", "The ID of the button pressed is " + newValue);
        DrawingFragment drawFrag = (DrawingFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Drawing);

        if (drawFrag != null) {
            //changeTool (part of DrawView) This is where I want to call the method
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawing);
    }

}
```

Fragment Code:

```
package com.example.chris.drawingtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.chris.drawingtest.R;

import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;

/**
 * Created by Chris on 11/28/2014.
 */
public class DrawingFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("onCreateView: ","This ran successfully");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawing, container, false);
        DrawView drawView = new DrawView(v.getContext());
        return v;
    }

    public static class DrawView extends View {

        private Path drawpath = new Path();
        private Paint drawpaint = new Paint();
        private Paint canvaspaint;
        private Canvas drawcanvas;
        private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

        private int paintColor = 0xFF000000;    //opaque black for pencil
        private int canvasColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;   //pure white for canvas

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            Log.d("DrawView: ", "method is called");

            drawpaint.setColor(paintColor);

            drawpaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            drawpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            drawpaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            drawpaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

            canvaspaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            Point p = getScreenSize(context);
            int w = p.x;
            int h = p.y;

            onSizeChanged(w,h,0,0);

        }

        public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context);

            Log.d("DrawView: ", "method is called");

            drawpaint.setColor(paintColor);

            drawpaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
            drawpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            drawpaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            drawpaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

            canvaspaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            Point p = getScreenSize(context);
            int w = p.x;
            int h = p.y;

            onSizeChanged(w,h,0,0);

        }

        public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context);

            Log.d("DrawView: ", "method is called");

            drawpaint.setColor(paintColor);

            drawpaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            drawpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            drawpaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            drawpaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

            canvaspaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            Point p = getScreenSize(context);
            int w = p.x;
            int h = p.y;

            onSizeChanged(w,h,0,0);

        }

// ------------------------ the method that I need to call ----------------------

        public boolean changeTool(int toolCode){
            switch(toolCode){
                case 0:
                    drawpaint.setColor(paintColor);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    drawpaint.setColor(canvasColor);
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

// ------------------------ the method that I need to call ----------------------


        protected Point getScreenSize(Context context) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            return size;
        }

        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);

            Log.d("OnSizeChanged: ", "method is called");

            canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            drawcanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            Log.d("onDraw: ", "method is called");

            canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap,0,0,canvaspaint);
            canvas.drawPath(drawpath, drawpaint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();

            Log.d("onTouchEvent: ", "method is called");

            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    drawpath.moveTo(touchX,touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    drawpath.lineTo(touchX,touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    drawcanvas.drawPath(drawpath, drawpaint);
                    drawpath.reset();
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have a method in your fragment that you call from the activity, and then the fragment method can pass it on to the view.

```
public class DrawingFragment extends Fragment {

    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("onCreateView: ","This ran successfully");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawing, container, false);
        drawView = new DrawView(v.getContext());
        return v;
    }

    public boolean changeTool(int toolCode){
        if (drawView != null) {
            drawView.changeTool(toolCode);
        }
    }
```

If you have a lot of such methods that you want to call, and it gets tedious to write all of these functions, you could consider moving some of your DrawView fields up to DrawingFragment, and then DrawingFragment could do the actual work, while DrawView referred to the fragment's fields as needed.

Comment: This looks like it should work fine, but I can't use drawView outside of onCreateView, even though it's public. Should I modify onCreateView's parameters to return drawView as well, or is that considered poor form?

Comment: Oh duh, just define it outside of onCreateView. Boy, that was simple of me. Thanks again for all of your help.